# Как закрыт или скрыть div через JavaScript без display: none;?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как закрыт или скрыть div через JavaScript без display: none; ? Или как закрыть div через 5 секунд после открытия? 
Например:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Чем вам display не нравится-то?

Comment: @Athari у меня ajax

Comment: А у меня апельсин. Чем не нравится-то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приблизительно так

```js
setTimeout(function(){$('#result').fadeOut();}, 5000);
```

```css
#result{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Сниппеты следует использовать, если вы хотите продемонстрировать полный пример, включающий HTML. Ваш код содержит только JS и никак не отображается на пустой странице. Вам следует или преобразовать сниппет в обычный блок кода, или дополнить его HTML.

Comment: Тут надо заметить, что конечный результат всех этих плясок следующий: `<div id="result" style="display: none;"></div>`.

Comment: @soledar10 Спасибо!